# How can I make an UIImageView load an image, but the URL is on a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uilabel

How can I make an `UIImageView` load an image, but the URL is on a `UILabel`?

More explanation: I have a `UILabel` containing an image web address, so I want this address to load an image on the `UIImageView`.  I suppose it involves some encoding but I have no idea how to do this.  Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourlabel.text]]];
```

Add the above image on your UIImageView:

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

EDIT: Go [here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) and read up on the "Categories" section. The sample method there checks if your string is a URL with a http:// prefix to it. Use that and if it returns NO, just add the string "http://" as a prefix to yourlabel.text and then pass it above instead of yourlabel.text

And yes as the link says, its just basic URL detection that just verifies if the string has been prefixed with http://

Sample code: A simple window based app

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = @"http://www.arthistoryarchive.com/arthistory/cubism/images/PabloPicasso-Weeping-Woman-with-Handkerchief-1937.jpg";
    UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:label.text]]];
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
    img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    [self.window addSubview:img];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The OP says that the URL is on the UILabel. I ask the person who downvoted this to come explain what's wrong.

Comment: It was me - I misread the question thought your answer was wrong, realised my mistake and reversed my downvote.

Comment: I understood the code, but it still non working,could you post the full code to load the image to the imageView!

Comment: What does the URL in your label look like? Post that first. Maybe your URL in that UILabel is the issue.

Comment: [http://revistaaz.com.br/wp-content/uploads/RevistaAz.com_.br_piau%C3%AD-021.jpg]

Comment: i fetch the link from an MYSQL db field but i think it should work as that bellow!imageText.text = @"http://revistaaz.com.br/wp-content/uploads/RevistaAz.com_.br_piau%C3%AD-021.jpg";
    UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageText.text]]];

Comment: Also just verify that your URL ends with the "jpg". Maybe its a Stack Overflow formatting error but I see an extra ] or a " after the .jpg

Comment: i added the prefix but i'm having problems to configure the UIView to display the image,i used to code the uiview in a different way,if possible could post the full code to display the image on the UIImageView!

Comment: but this does't make the image load on the UIImageView,that's my worry!

Comment: im clueless as to what you're doing wrong. In the sample code above I load up the UIImage with the NSData from the URL (which I get from the label). And then I create a UIImageView and set the above UIImage to it. Thats all. The UIImageView contains the image now and you just need to add the UIImageView as the subView to whatever your parent view is.

Comment: i'll upload the source code.Take a look at the DetailViewController,i want to load the uiimageview from the imageText.label! the link is http://www.megaupload.com/?d=GJN6NRTU

Comment: Yes. you have not added the UIImageView as a subView at all. In the viewDidLoad of your DetailViewController.m file at the end add the line [self.view addSubview:img];

Comment: it loaded the image fine as a frame(the image took all screen),if i want to display this image on the UIImageView,can you help just a little bit more?

Comment: set the frame of the UIImageView accordingly. I've set it as 0,0,768,1024 which is the entire screen in Portrait. Set the img.frame properly to your needs.

Comment: i tried this but the image still occupying all the screen,there's no way to make the image appear on the UIImageView?

Comment: Ok look. Change that img.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024) to this: img.frame = CGRectMake (20,20,250,200); Do you see any difference?

Comment: i found my mistake!Ok,now is working perfectly.Thanks for your time and sorry for anything.

Comment: You are apparently having a lot difficulties in grasping that the UIImageView is a subView to DetailViewController's view. And that the UIImageView has a frame property which you need to set according to your needs. The image is in the UIImageView. You issue is that the UIImageView occupies entire screen (which is because of the frame I had set for my iPad simulator). Set the frame properly please.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think.

First, convert your URL string into an NSURL

```
NSURL*   imageUrl  = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
```

Then load the data at that URL

```
NSData*  imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
```

Then load that data into a UIImage

```
UIImage* image     = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

And finally, tell your UIImageView to display that image

```
imageView.image = image;
```